# How to apply CSS on custom tag in Angular 2/5?

Tags: angular, angular5

I've installed the [Google ReCaptcha (ng-recaptcha)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha) component to my app, and was wondering if there is a way to apply some styles **to children elements** of the generated, in my case, `<re-captcha></re-captcha>` element.

For example:

```
re-captcha{
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /*works*/
}

re-captcha div{
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /*doesn't work*/
}
```

Could you please share some experience of achieving the desired result?

**UPDATE:**

The following works however, if set directly in DevTools...

```
re-captcha div{
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

Comment: `foo { color: red; }`. The same way you style anything else. Apply a class or id, and apply a style. You might need to poke at the view encapsulation or use the `::ng-deep` selector.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thanks for you comment, however I didn't clarify that I need style children elements. Please see the updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code snippet:

```
re-captcha /deep/ div{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Used ::ng-deep instead, but thanks for the showing the right direction. Worked as expected.

Answer (score 7):

This is caused by the view encapsulation setting of the component.

You can use a `/deep/` or `::ng-deep` selector to target child components in Native or Emulated (which is default) modes, in which abbasak's answer will work.

Comment: `::ng-deep` is preferred per the docs though all are deprecated. Refer: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification

Comment: Remember `ng-deep` is now deprecated (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Answer (score 2):

Two options: either set these styles you need as global styles in your app(you likely have something like `styles.scss` in your `.angular-client.json`), or you can try setting `ViewEncapsulation.None in the metadata of the component that wraps your`` element.

Comment: Or try `/deep/` rule like the other answer suggests.