# CSS style from app.component.css not getting applied to the tabs body content

Tags: angular

Can you tell me why the padding is not getting applied here even though i have the padding-top set to 20px in my app.component.css file.
It will work if i set it in the styles.css file.  Not sure why its not working when I move the css property to the app.component.css file.

app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

app.component.html file:

```
<mat-tab-group class="redThis">
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

app.component.css file

```
.mat-tab-body-content{
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: CSS is encapsuled on Angular. Use :host deep to be allow to do that or put your style on styles.(s)css. Check the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles :

Comment: I think you have the wrong selector.. in your css is you are specifying mat-tab-body-content.  you can try changing your app.css definition for padding to .mat-tab{padding-top:20px}

Comment: Same issue as this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540906/how-to-apply-css-on-custom-tag-in-angular-2-5/49542285#49542285

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I actually got it to work after researching about @Gilsdav's comment

In my app.component.css file I changed it to

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-content{
    padding-top:20px
}
```

Its working now.
Thanks! Learned something new today! :)

Comment: Note: `ng-deep` will be [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). If you can safely apply the padding-top to all material tab contents, then you could put it in your styles.css to apply it globally.

Comment: A hideous solution to a simple issue

Comment: It's actually bad enough that if someone told me this existed prior to starting to use Angular, I'd have refused to use it.

Answer (score 8):

In the root directory ( where the `main.ts` is ) there's a `style.css` or `style.scss` ( depends on what you chose ) - placing the code there - is global.

I believe that `app.component.scss` applies only to `app.component.html` directly ( lazy load pages aren't getting that css )