# How to use an icon inside MatSlideToggle in Angular Material 11?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, material-design

On the [Angular Material components overview](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) there's an example of slide toogles with icons:

[image]

This looks really nice. Unfortunately this example isn't explained in the actual docs of the component.

So what I tried is this:

```
<mat-slide-toggle labelPosition="before" color="primary">
  <mat-icon>dark_mode</mat-icon>
  Dark Mode
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

I have this wrapped inside a menu and the result looks like this:

[image]

So it's almost there, but not really. Everything is not aligned correctly.

My questions are:

- How to align the icon, label and toggle correctly?
- How is it possible to increase the distance between label and toggle like in the examples from the docs?

[Try it on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bk2crx)

Comment: Create complete demo using this - https://codesandbox.io/s/

Comment: @m4n0 Added [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bk2crx)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://nimb.ws/lUJEIu

Comment: @m4n0 Yes. It almost looks like the example on the Material documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the generated CSS in the `app.component.css` file:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-content {
  display: flex; /* Turn into a flexbox container for alignment */
}

.material-icons {
  margin-right: 5px; /* Spacing from the content */
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-label-before .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
  margin-left: 50px; /* Spacing from the icon and content */
}
```

It could have been enough to add `.mat-slide-toggle-content` or `.mat-slide-toggle-label-before .mat-slide-toggle-bar` but for some reason it was not working. The solution here came handy although it looks unorthodox: [CSS style from app.component.css not getting applied to the tabs body content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738999/css-style-from-app-component-css-not-getting-applied-to-the-tabs-body-content)

You can see the full code here: [StackBlitz Demo](https://angular-ivy-mkjzj7.stackblitz.io)